# How to calculate the probability of at least k events each of probability m in a set of N independent trials.

Tags: probability

I have a probability of an event $=p$. For example ($p = 0.01$).  I have $N$ (say $1000$) independent trials.  I seek to calculate the probability of having exactly $k$ ($k= 1 \dots N$) events of in the set.

I have that the probability of having $0$ events is $(1-p)^N$, which is to say the probability of getting no event $(1-p)$ in each of the $N$ trials.

After that I am not sure where to go.  Simulations give very reasonable answers - i.e. a more or less Gaussian centered at 10 (1% of 1000 using the examples given).  But I am stumped for a closed form solution.

Answer (score 2):

In your example, where the probability of an individual event is small and the expected number of events is fairly small, a [Poisson distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_distribution) will be a better approximation.  There is a "closed form" for the cumulative distribution function so you don't have to do the sum if you have the incomplete gamma function available to you.  The probability of at most $k$ events is $\frac {\Gamma(k+1,\lambda)}{k!}$ where $\lambda=Np$ is the expected number of events.  The probability of exactly $k$ events is $\frac {\lambda^k}{k!}e^{-\lambda}$.  The Poisson distribution becomes Gaussian as the number of expected events becomes large.

Comment: Thanks, I am doing the analysis in Excel and there appears to be a way to get the incomplete gamma function.  I will try.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Probability of having exactly $k$ events (occurence probability $p$) out of $N$ is

$$ \binom{N}{k} p^{k} (1-p)^{N-k}$$

See [Binomial Distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution) (and that indeed can be [approximated with the Gaussian](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution#Normal_approximation)).

Comment: Thanks, the form you provided gives the probability for exactly k, so if I sum from 1 to k I will get the answer I need.  Probably the integral to the Gaussian would give a good approximation.

Comment: You can aproximate the binomial distribution to normal only when N is big (in this case, it is) and p is 'far' from 0 or 1. Take a look at: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution#Normal_approximation